# QtConcurrent::run proceed after new thread has been created

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency, qt5

I have to run the same function over and over again for a large volume of data.

This is where I would be using `QtConcurrent::run` so that I can work with 5 objects at the same time. This is my code, which is meant toloop through for each dataset:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < (dataset.size())/3; j++){
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 2) {
            QtConcurrent::run(this, &SomeObject::doWork, dataset.at(i+3*j));
            i++;
        }
    }
```

**Problem:** I noticed that there are times when `doWork` is not invoked for some data in the dataset. As [this QT Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html#run) says, I believe the thread is not being created for the missing data. How can I ensure that I am dealing with 2 dataSet at the same time (and getting successful results) before calling the next pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < (dataset.size())/3; j++){
    QFutureSynchronizer<void> synchronizer;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 2) {
        synchronizer.addFuture(QtConcurrent::run(this, &SomeObject::doWork, dataset.at(i+3*j)));
        i++;
    }
    synchronizer.waitForFinished();
}
```